# Piping a stream to a stream with custom results

Tags: node.js, express, stream

After reading and marginally understanding the [node stream handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), I want to use streams whenever it seems appropriate/possible.

I have a request that uploads a file which should be written to another spot on the file system.  This is done via:

```
readStream = fs.createReadStream(request.files.file.path);
readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(targetPath));
```

This works great, but I want to pipe the result of the write stream to a response -- specifically I want the target path to be piped to the result when it's successful.  Right now I'm doing:

```
readStream.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(targetPath)).on("close", function () 
    serverResponse.send(200, targetPath);
});
```

This works fine, but I feel like it is more verbose than it needs to be and I should be able to call `.pipe` on the result as in `read.pipe(write).pipe(respose)`.

Is there something I can do to get the write stream to pipe the target path to the response or better way I can go about doing what I'm doing?

Comment: Your write stream is a `Writable` only stream, which means that you can't read from it. The other solution would be to create a `Transform` stream that writes the input data to a file but also buffers it, so that the data can be written to the output of the stream when the data stops coming (`on('end')`); but this defeats the stream purposes as you will have to buffer to whole file in memory

Comment: The main issue is that you want to do something with all of the data (i.e. write all the data to the response stream) at the end of the stream (i.e. when you're sure that your local file has been correctly written). Without buffering or re-reading from disk, I don't think there is an elegant solution to your problem

Comment: Is this question still active? I think duplex stream might be good solution here.

Comment: @EdinM question is still active if you have a good, working solution